# Does the iOS Box app respond to a custom URL scheme?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, url-scheme, box-api

I'd love to be able to launch the native Box iOS app directly from my own native iOS app. For example, Dropbox uses `db-api-1://`, Facebook uses `fb://`, Square uses `square://`, etc.

Does Box for iOS use a similar URL scheme? If so, is there documentation outlining what parameters it can parse? If not, is there another way of launching it from my app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've inspected the Info.plist of the app:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.box.boxapp</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>box</string>
            <string>box-login</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.box.docinteraction.upload</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>box-upload-all</string>
            <string>box-upload-all-direct</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

So there are 4 url schemes in total: box, box-login, box-upload-all and box-upload-all-direct. But its hard to use them if you don't have any documentation...

Comment: Thanks @phix23, I had no idea one could inspect 3rd party app plists! Since seeing your answer a few minutes ago, I've peered into the Box.app package and confirmed your findings. Fascinating that you can also see their storyboards, nibs and png's (among other things). Thanks again!

Comment: http://developers.box.com/onecloud/ has info on what each of the schemes do if you want to read more there.

Comment: @seanrose you mentioned that the box schemes are listed in the documentation.  is this still true?  i do not see them

Comment: Looks like the documentation moved to a new location: https://developers.box.com/deep-linking/